# vim: change the status line color in insert mode

Tags: vim

I found this snippet to change the status line color when i go to insert mode:

```
" first, enable status line always
set laststatus=2

" now set it up to change the status line based on mode
if version >= 700
  au InsertEnter * hi StatusLine term=reverse ctermbg=5 gui=undercurl guisp=Magenta
  au InsertLeave * hi StatusLine term=reverse ctermfg=0 ctermbg=2 gui=bold,reverse
endif
```

Now, when i go to insert mode the status line go to violet color, but I want to change it to go to red color. I changed Magenta by Red, but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `:help`, you can find out what each of those attributes mean.

`guisp` is used for the "special" color of the highlight. In this case, it's the color of the undercurl effect. It sounds like you want to change the actual highlight color, so try this:

```
au InsertEnter * hi StatusLine term=reverse ctermbg=5 gui=undercurl guisp=Magenta guibg=Red
```

And in fact, if you just use a GUI Vim, you don't need any of the terminal options:

```
au InsertEnter * hi StatusLine guibg=Red
au InsertLeave * hi StatusLine guibg=#ccdc90
```

For `InsertLeave`, I just used the my normal `StatusLine` color as an example. You should be able to find it in your colorscheme file.

Incidentally, `guibg` actually affects the text color, while `guifg` affect the line color...

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any mention of whether you are using a gui version of Vim, or just Vim in a terminal.

If you are in a terminal you need to change `"ctermbg=5"` to `"ctermbg=red"` instead.  In this case `"5"` translates to `"DarkMagenta"`.  Vim will accept numbers or color names for these attributes.

More information can be found in under sections 2 and 3 under the [Highlight Command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#%3ahighlight) from the Vim Syntax Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Great solution: [Powerline plugin](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline)

[image: Normal mode]
[image: Insert mode]

Comment: Looks awesome but installation instructions fail under Debian Squeeze :-(

Answer (score 0):

## Neovim

See [nvim_set_hl()](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_set_hl()) for all options.

```lua
vim.cmd("colorscheme walh-gruvbox") -- set colorscheme

local insertCallBack = function()
  vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "StatusLine", { ctermfg = 0, ctermbg = 12 })
end

local NormalCallBack = function()
  vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "StatusLine", { ctermfg = "NONE", ctermbg = 0 })
end

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "InsertEnter" }, {
  pattern = "*",
  callback = insertCallBack,
})

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "InsertLeave" }, {
  pattern = "*",
  callback = NormalCallBack,
})
```

[image: NormalMode]
[image: InsertMode]