# Change appearance in sublime text 3 when switching mode in Vintage

Tags: vim, editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is it possible to change some part of the editor's appearance when switching between command mode and insert mode in Vintage?

By default, when I switch modes, sublime only shows the text `COMMAND MODE` and `INSERT MODE` in the status bar. This is too small for more. I'm looking for something more obvious like this question: [vim: change the status line color in insert mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147157/vim-change-the-status-line-color-in-insert-mode), but in Sublime

Comment: it may not answer your question, but, vim can do all about that. So far I haven't found a single "vim-plugin" of other editors/Ides, which was comparable with vim. If you love vim, and that Editor X was not a must for you. use vim.

Comment: I will use Vim in the future but now I'm learning the edition keys... I don't switch directly to Vim bc it will be very traumatic for me at this moment :_(

Comment: If you really want to switch to vim some day. I suggest you for critical editing, using your favorite Editor, but do all rest editing in vim. (email, SO question/answer, your private projects, testing ...).  The best way to learn it is to use it.

Comment: SergiGP, you can start with `vimtutor` to learn `vim`.

Comment: The author of the Vintageous plugin has stated (on BountySource) that it is not possible.  I don't know if it's ***actually not possible*** with Sublime's API, or if he just means that his plugin can't do it, but quite possibly the obstacle is Sublime itself.  Perhaps file a feature request with Sublime?

Answer (score 0):

The following command will update the current view color scheme on insert/normal mode changes.

Obviously you wouldn't want to just toggle solarized light/dark when the vim mode changes, but the following example command should give you an idea of the possibilities.

```
class OnVimModeChange(sublime_plugin.EventListener):

    def on_post_text_command(self, view, name, args):
        if view.settings().get('command_mode'):
            view.settings().set('color_scheme', 'Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Solarized (Dark).tmTheme')
        else:
            view.settings().set('color_scheme', 'Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Solarized (Light).tmTheme')
```